# Issues installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on HP z210 workstation

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, hp, lts

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an HP z210 workstation (only OS on it is FreeDos) via a USB flash drive and it keeps slowing down or freezing when I'm at the install screen. I've tried adding `nomodeset` and booting in Safe Mode. I've also seen a few people saying to update code, but I'm not sure how to get to the code during thee install process.

When it doesn't just freeze on me I get the error:

```
ipmi:dmi: Base address is zero, assuming no IPMI interface.
```

What can I do to properly install Ubuntu? Please help!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @K7AAY! I've updated my Question

Comment: Did you check for errors per https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu ? If not, suggest you do that. Iif the ISO does not match the checksum, redownload it & checksum the new download. If no flaw was shown in the download, suggest you try a non-GNOME distro, such as Xubuntu 20.04 http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/xubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso and checksum it against http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/SHA256SUMS before making a new LiveUSB for install to isolate the problem.